# How to change layout after orientation changed without reloading app

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I would like to change the layout after the screen orientation changed without reloading the app.

I added the following into `AndroidManifest` for not reload the app after orientation changed and it worked:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

But now, I would like to change the layout when the orientation changes WITHOUT reloading app.

For example for `layout-land`, I have `example1.xml` and for `layout-port`, I have example2.xml with other different code.

Comment: If you have two layouts with the same name in different folder than they should be changed automatically

Comment: i have two layout with same name in different folder.. but not changed automatically but only if I re-open the app

Comment: I would reccomend you to put the logic into fragment and then just show fragment inside activity. Layout also sould be inflated in fragment

Comment: I have two layout with same name in different folder.. but not changed automatically but only if I re-open the app becuse there is android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in Android Manifest but i would to switch to layout-land to layout-port without reload app

Comment: My layout is inside the FrameLayout... i show fragment inside the activity.

Comment: I understood. Just try to put all logic inside fragment and put that fragment inside your activity. By fragment I mean creating new class that extends Fragment class

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I've already done.

Comment: Did you fix your problem

Comment: For example..  in MainActivity.java i show fragment in this way... FragmentExample fragment = new FragmentExample();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: But the problem is that i changed screen orientation, the layout not switch. The layout swtich only if i re-open the app.

Comment: You need to switch layout of the fragment or of the activity?

Comment: switch the layout fragment.. because in Main Activity i have Fragment container that show all layouts  of the fragment